# Trying hard to see the fault in my proof - though it is incorrect!

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

consider the function $ f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1-x} $ on the interval $[0,1)$

My claim is that the function is bounded in this interval (even though it's not), I'm asking if someone could tell me where I've gone wrong in the following proof:

Aruging my contradiction, suppose $f$ is unbounded on $[0,1)$. Then there is a sequence $x_n \in [0,1)$ such that $|f(x_n)| \to +\infty$. Since the sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded between 0 and 1, the BW theorem guarantees that it has a convergence subsequence $(x_{jn})$ and we shall denote its limit by: $x_{\infty} = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} x_{jn} $

now since $f$ is continuous in this interval we know that $f(x_{jn}) \to f(x_\infty)$ but this is impossible since $(f(x_{jn}))$ is a subsequence of $(f(x_n))$ and $|f(x_n)| \to +\infty$ which implies that $|f(x_{jn})| \to +\infty$. So we conclude that our initial assumption is wrong and f must be bounded on the given interval.

thanks

Comment: The subsequence could converge to $1$, which is a limit point of $[0,1)$, after all.

Comment: $[0,1)$ is not compact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem states that any sequence on a *compact* subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a convergent subsequence. $[0,1)$ is not compact.

Comment: Or in simple, Calculus I lingo:  the BW theorem is appliable *only* to closed, bounded intervals *or* finite unions of such. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Just trying to avoid possible misunderstandings of beginning students which may not have yet studied "compact spaces". Your answer is, of course, correct andsimpler to state than "closed, bounded intervals and finite unions of such".

Comment: @DonAntonio:  Not to mention that there are plenty of compact sets which are not finite unions of closed bounded intervals, e.g., any convergent sequence, or the Cantor set.

Comment: @JasonDeVito The BW theorem applies to all compact subsets because in a metric space compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent.

Comment: @IBWiglin:  Right, but I interpreted DonAntonio's comment (perhaps incorrectly) as asserting that compact is equivalent to being a finite union of closed intervals and my hope was to correct this ;-).  Sorry for not being clearer.